# Pass cppFlag values to the C++ code using Android Studio and Experimental Gradle Plugin

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, gradle-experimental

```
void DoSomething()
{   ...     
    m_a = new SomeContext<SOMETHING>(m_data);   
    ... 
}
```

Using Android Studio's Experimental Gradle Plugin, how do I pass the value of SOMETHING as "somevalue"? I think I should be using cppFlags.add('-DSOMETHING=somevalue') but this is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `model`, `android`, `ndk` block, you can add

```
#set cppFlag
cppFlags.add("-DSOMETHING=awesome".toString())
```

And it will be used during compilation.